# How to call a method from another method class when I can't use self

Tags: pygqis

I want to call show_notification in the MainWindow class of the object the SelectTool class, which was created from the object of the MainWindow class.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, cestaVrstvy, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # ........more code

    def run(self):
        self.create_top_ToolBar()
        self.create_statusBar()
        # ...... more code

    def create_top_ToolBar(self):
        self.tlacidloPan = QAction(QIcon('Icons\\move.png'), 'Pan', self)
        self.tlacidloSelect = QAction(QIcon('Icons\\mapinfo.png'), 'Info ...', self)

        self.tlacidloPan.setCheckable(True)
        self.tlacidloSelect.setCheckable(True)
        self.myTool = SelectTool(self.mojePlatno,self.crs.ellipsoidAcronym())
        self.myTool.setAction(self.tlacidloSelect)
        self.tlacidloPan.triggered.connect(self.pan)
        self.tlacidloSelect.triggered.connect(self.select)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Nástroje mapy")
        self.toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(30, 30))
        self.toolbar.setMinimumHeight(self.vyskaToolBaru)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.tlacidloPan)
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.tlacidloSelect)
        self.toolPan = QgsMapToolPan(self.mojePlatno)
        self.toolPan.setAction(self.tlacidloPan)
        self.mojePlatno.setMapTool(self.toolPan)
        self.tlacidloSelect.setEnabled(False)

    def create_statusBar(self):
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusText = QLabel("")
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusText, 1)
        # *** more code

    def pan(self):
        self.vyber_widget.setVisible(False)
        self.mojePlatno.setMapTool(self.toolPan)

    def select(self):
        self.vyber_widget.setVisible(True)
        self.mojePlatno.setMapTool(self.myTool)

    def show_notification(self, oznam):
        print(oznam)
        self.statusText.setText(oznam)
    # ***more code ** *


class SelectTool(QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature):
    def __init__(self, platno, elipsoidAcronym):
        super(SelectTool, self).__init__(platno)
        self.linkedcanvas = platno
        self.featureId = None
        self.elipsoidAcronym = elipsoidAcronym

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        point = self.linkedcanvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
        xGeoSur = point.x()
        yGeoSur = point.y()
        # ***  more code
        message = "Some text ...."
        # XX XX here I want to call the show_notification(message) method in MainWindow
        XXX.show_notification(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

I already figured it out. If it helps someone else, I'm writing an answer.

When initing SelectTool, you need to add the self.statusText argument and then directly call the setText method on self.statusText ...

```
class SelectTool(QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature):
    def __init__(self, platno, elipsoidAcronym, statusText):
        super(SelectTool, self).__init__(platno)
        self.linkedcanvas = platno
        self.featureId = None
        self.elipsoidAcronym = elipsoidAcronym
        self.statusText = statusText

def create_top_ToolBar(self):
        self.tlacidloPan = QAction(QIcon('Icons\\move.png'), 'Pan', self)
        self.tlacidloSelect = QAction(QIcon('Icons\\mapinfo.png'), 'Info ...', self)
        self.tlacidloPan.setCheckable(True)
        self.tlacidloSelect.setCheckable(True)
        self.myTool = SelectTool(self.mojePlatno,self.crs.ellipsoidAcronym(), self.statusText)
....

  def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        point = self.linkedcanvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
        xGeoSur = point.x()
        yGeoSur = point.y()
        # ***  more code
        self.statusText(message)
```